# Can a client use an api key directly or should it make a request to my server first?

Tags: react-native, google-maps-api-3

I have a google maps api key for a mobile app (react native) I'm developing and I'm not sure what the best design pattern is. Is there a way to use it to have each client make their requests to google directly? Or should each client talk to my server, which makes the request, and hands the results back to the client?
Any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**well, This is an interesting one!**

I would say we can use it in ways like these:

1. You can use some config package to hide the env inside native code using
   **.env.yml** files of sorts ( look into [react-native-ultimate-config](https://github.com/maxkomarychev/react-native-ultimate-config) )
2. It can be from server-side but in that cae, I wanna know that how you will pass it to manifest file on runtime? in android or in app-Delegate file for iOS?

you might need to write modules on both Native sides to handle the keys on runtime based on the API response from the JS side!  but I highly doubt that a meta will be allowed for updating inside a manifest file for android once the app is made! or so is the case in the Delegate file for iOS.